# Grouped data is taking longer time to process in dataflow

Tags: java, group-by, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am using apache beam sdk to write code. Here I have a PCollection that contain large amount of data on that data I am applying group by or creating a group of that data. Once I have grouped data I have applied Pardo on it and inside processElement,iterating each tablerow (also there is for loop inside it) and processing it and creating a final tablerow then writing it to biqquery.

Data around 42k is taking 1 hours time to load in table.
This is the least amount of data, once data is increase it will die.

Can anyone help me or give me some good suggestions.

Thanks.!!!

[image]

Comment: Why don't you have a `ParDo` to process the grouped data?

Comment: Yeah doing same,but still it is taking more time.

Comment: Can you post your pipeline or a sketch or your pipeline ?

Comment: What is the number of elements per group ? Also why do you need to group elements before writing ? Note that Dataflow cannot parallelize the reading (and iteration) of a single group. So if you have a group with a large number of values (a hot key) that could take a significant amount of time to process.

Comment: Can we apply order by on gropped elements.?

Comment: The number is vary on group basis. actually the for loop inside the iterable is taking time as i have to set the values which is present inside the table row of iterable.

Comment: Once you group elements, you get values of a given key as a iterator. So you can read or iterate them as needed. But note that this can be expensive if you have a large number of elements per key. Beam does not provide ordering guarantees on elements of a PCollection. Please see here regarding hotkeys - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/writing-dataflow-pipelines-with-scalability-in-mind

Comment: @user_a27 did chamikara's suggestions helped you?

Comment: yes beam does not provide ordering functionality but we can use collections and perform sorting. @muscat chamikara's suggestion was good but it did not solved my issue.